# Difference between ASP.NET MVC 1 and 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I made several websites with MVC 1 and now I'm ready to skip the version 2 to go ahead and play with the version 3 directly.

Without giving to much details, can you provide me with the biggest key concepts that the version 3 brings to the table versus version 1 (version 2 included)?

I will research on those topics afterwards.

For example I heard about "areas" in v2. I'm looking for those big things you programmers think it's worth to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documents [What's new in MVC 2](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc) and [ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes) provide a good overview.

MVC 2:

- Templated Helpers
- Areas
- Client-side Validation
- Child action rendering
- Data Annotations support
- More model binding
- Asynchronous controllers
- Bunch of other stuff

MVC 3:

- Razor view engine
- Unobtrusive client-side validation and jQuery support
- Dependency Injection support
- More Validation
- JSON model binding
- Granular request validation
- Requires .NET 4
- Bunch of other stuff

In addition there are all the blog posts about MVC by [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx), [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/tags/aspnetmvc/default.aspx), [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/aspnet_mvc/), and a bunch of others you can search for with very little effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I'll have to do some studying before beginning, +1

Comment: Just for supplyment, The modelbinder of mvc3 supports Json now,You can post data using json format directly.

Comment: @bearing09: No need to serialize your data to query/post format? Directly in JSON? That is just nice. I do it so often.

Answer (score 2):

The [Razor View Engine](http://ironshay.com/post/The-Razor-View-Engine-Basics.aspx) is so much nicer than Web Forms. One thing to note about it is that it automatically encodes html - this is much safer but you'll need to call [Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) in your helpers to return unencoded html.

I'm also digging [ViewBag](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx) so far, it's basically a dynamic, nicer ViewData and from what I can tell, relieves the need for ViewModels (although still not as nice as Rails).

You might find something like this in an MVC 1 View

```
<%= ViewData["Title"] %>
```

With Razor in MVC 3 it'd look like this

```
@ViewBag.Title
```

Comment: ViewData still works fine, in fact, they both reference the same dictionary, so they can be used interchangeably

Comment: Right - it still works (as does Web Forms VE). Which do you prefer?

Comment: interesting.. a new way to render pages. Thanks +1